# Flutter Bloc; 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-navigation

Flutter Version: 2.1.0

Flutter Bloc Version: ^7.0.1

Dart: 2.13.0

Getting this error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding the missing arguments.dart(not_enough_positional_arguments).

Is there anything I'm wrong

[image]

My Sidebar Layout Where the error occured:

```
 body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates>(
                builder: (context, NavigationState) {
              return NavigationState as Widget;
            }),
            SideBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

My Bloc Navigation file:

```
import '/Pages/DeviceLocation/DeviceLocation.dart';

import '/Pages/Devices/DeviceLanding.dart';

import '../../LandingScreen/components/body.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/GasChart.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/HumChart.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/MoisChart.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/NurChart.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/PhChart.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/TemChart.dart';
import '../../SensorScreen/charts/chartComponents/NurCard.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

enum NavigationEvents {
  // DashboardClickEvent,
  LandingScreenBodyClickEvent,
  TemChartClickEvent,
  HumChartClickEvent,
  MoisChartClickEvent,
  PhChartClickEvent,
  NurChartClickEvent,
  GasChartClickEvent,
  DevicesClickEvent,
  DevicesLocationClickEvent,
  AccountClickEvent,
  SettingsClickEvent
}

abstract class NavigationStates {}

class NavigationBloc extends Bloc<NavigationEvents, NavigationStates> {
  NavigationBloc(NavigationStates initialState) : super(initialState);

  @override
  NavigationStates get initialState => LandingScreenBody();

  @override
  Stream<NavigationStates> mapEventToState(NavigationEvents event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case NavigationEvents.LandingScreenBodyClickEvent:
        yield LandingScreenBody();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.TemChartClickEvent:
        yield TemChart();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.HumChartClickEvent:
        yield HumChart();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.MoisChartClickEvent:
        yield MoisChart();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.PhChartClickEvent:
        yield PhChart();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.NurChartClickEvent:
        yield NurChart();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.GasChartClickEvent:
        yield GasChart();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.DevicesClickEvent:
        yield DeviceLanding();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.DevicesLocationClickEvent:
        yield DevicesLocation();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrog?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass the state to the bloc constructor, this should work

```
NavigationBloc() : super(LandingScreenBody());
```

and in flutter_bloc 7.0.0, there's no `initialState` getter any more, so you have to remove it as well

Comment: You mean, I should remove:                                                                                          
   ` avigationBloc(NavigationStates initialState) : super(initialState);
       @override
  NavigationStates get initialState => LandingScreenBody();                                            
  `                                                                                                                                                                  and  just replace it with               
      ` NavigationBloc() : super(LandingScreenBody());?
`

Comment: @isofttech Exactly.

Comment: checkout the migration guide https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration for version 5.0.0

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for me. I had a problem after updating flutter_bloc and a number of other dependencies, and I was not able to realize where is the source of my problem. Now I know.

Comment: @kokserek you're welcom